# Add id attribute to first child

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I have an XML document and I need to get the value of the id attribute if present if not create it and then assign a value to the first occurence of an element. I'm able to get the Field element and set a new id but in the next else if the id attribute I just set gets overwritten. How would I specify for first occurrence of the element assign id="i1" all other children assign id="s1"?

XML Sample

```
    <isolationMainProcedure>
  <isolationStep id="i-001">
    <note>
      <notePara>xxx xx</notePara>
    </note>
    <action>xxx xx<acronym id="rcm">xxx xx<acronymTerm>xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx<acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronym>xxx xx</action>
    <isolationStepQuestion>xxx xx</isolationStepQuestion>
    <isolationStepAnswer>
      <yesNoAnswer>
        <yesAnswer nextActionRefId="e-001" />
        <noAnswer nextActionRefId="s-001" />
      </yesNoAnswer>
    </isolationStepAnswer>
  </isolationStep>
  <isolationProcedureEnd id="e-001">
    <action>xxx xx<acronymTerm internalRefId="rcm">xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx</action>
    <action>xxx xx<dmRef>xxx xx<dmRefIdent>xxx xxxxx xx</dmRefIdent>xxx xx</dmRef>xxx xx</action>
  </isolationProcedureEnd>
  <isolationStep id="s-001">
    <action>xxx xx</action>
    <isolationStepQuestion>xxx xx</isolationStepQuestion>
    <isolationStepAnswer>
      <yesNoAnswer>
        <yesAnswer nextActionRefId="s-002" />
        <noAnswer nextActionRefId="e-002" />
      </yesNoAnswer>
    </isolationStepAnswer>
  </isolationStep>
  <isolationProcedureEnd id="e-002">
    <action>xxx xx<acronym id="gcs">xxx xx<acronymTerm>xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx<acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronym>xxx xx<acronym id="sbs">xxx xx<acronymTerm>xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx<acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronym>xxx xx<acronym id="ramts">xxx xx<acronymTerm>xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx<acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronym>xxx xx</action>
    <action>xxx xx<acronymTerm internalRefId="gcs">xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx<acronymTerm internalRefId="sbs">xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx<acronymTerm internalRefId="ramts">xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx</action>
  </isolationProcedureEnd>
</isolationMainProcedure>
```

Code

```
        Dim stepLeadingZeror = stepIndex.ToString("D4")
        For Each Field As XmlElement In xmldocNode.SelectNodes("isolationStep|isolationProcedureEnd")
            If (Field.HasAttribute("id")) Then
                Dim initExistingStep As String = Field.GetAttribute("id")
                Dim newIntStepID = "Fi" + fiCount.ToString + "i-" + stepLeadingZeror
                Field.SetAttribute("id", newIntStepID)
                Debug.Write(vbCr + "old Step ID: " + initExistingStep + " /  new Step ID " + newIntStepID)
                dictionaryRenumberID.Add(initExistingStep, newIntStepID)
            ElseIf Field.Name = "isolationStep" Then
                For Each Attribute As XmlAttribute In Field.Attributes
                    If Attribute.Name = "id" Then
                        Dim existingStep = Field.GetAttribute("id")
                        newStepID = "Fi" + fiCount.ToString + "s-" + stepLeadingZeror
                        Field.SetAttribute("id", newStepID)
                        Debug.Write(vbCr + "old Step ID: " + existingStep + " /  new Step ID " + newStepID)
                        dictionaryRenumberID.Add(existingStep, newStepID)
                    End If
                Next
            ElseIf Field.Name = "isolationProcedureEnd" Then
                For Each Attribute As XmlAttribute In Field.Attributes
                    If Attribute.Name = "id" Then
                        Dim existingEndStep = Field.GetAttribute("id")
                        newEndStepID = "Fi" + fiCount.ToString + "e-" + stepLeadingZeror
                        Field.SetAttribute("id", newEndStepID)
                        Debug.Write(vbCr + "old End ID: " + existingEndStep + " /  new End ID " + newEndStepID)
                        dictionaryRenumberID.Add(existingEndStep, newEndStepID)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            stepIndex += 1
        Next
```

Comment: Are you sure `If Attribute.Name = "id" Then`  in the ElseIf is running?  If `Field` have the `id` attribute then loop will hit `if` part not the `ElseIf` so not sure why you are checking `Attribute.Name` in your ElseIf conditions.

Comment: @supputuri Good point. I can change it just to set the attribute id. But that doesn't solve my problem of changing the first elements id attribute assign it the value of "i1" then all other elements increment the value of "s2...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XElement

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    ' xe=XElement.Load("path here")
    'for testing use a literal
    xe = <isolationMainProcedure>
             <isolationStep id="i-001">
                 <note>
                     <notePara>xxx xx</notePara>
                 </note>
                 <action>xxx xx<acronym id="rcm">xxx xx<acronymTerm>xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx<acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronym>xxx xx</action>
                 <isolationStepQuestion>xxx xx</isolationStepQuestion>
                 <isolationStepAnswer>
                     <yesNoAnswer>
                         <yesAnswer nextActionRefId="e-001"/>
                         <noAnswer nextActionRefId="s-001"/>
                     </yesNoAnswer>
                 </isolationStepAnswer>
             </isolationStep>
             <isolationProcedureEnd id="e-001">
                 <action>xxx xx<acronymTerm internalRefId="rcm">xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx</action>
                 <action>xxx xx<dmRef>xxx xx<dmRefIdent>xxx xxxxx xx</dmRefIdent>xxx xx</dmRef>xxx xx</action>
             </isolationProcedureEnd>
             <isolationStep id="s-001">
                 <action>xxx xx</action>
                 <isolationStepQuestion>xxx xx</isolationStepQuestion>
                 <isolationStepAnswer>
                     <yesNoAnswer>
                         <yesAnswer nextActionRefId="s-002"/>
                         <noAnswer nextActionRefId="e-002"/>
                     </yesNoAnswer>
                 </isolationStepAnswer>
             </isolationStep>
             <isolationProcedureEnd id="e-002">
                 <action>xxx xx<acronym id="gcs">xxx xx<acronymTerm>xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx<acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronym>xxx xx<acronym id="sbs">xxx xx<acronymTerm>xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx<acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronym>xxx xx<acronym id="ramts">xxx xx<acronymTerm>xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx<acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronymDefinition>xxx xx</acronym>xxx xx</action>
                 <action>xxx xx<acronymTerm internalRefId="gcs">xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx<acronymTerm internalRefId="sbs">xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx<acronymTerm internalRefId="ramts">xxx xx</acronymTerm>xxx xx</action>
             </isolationProcedureEnd>
         </isolationMainProcedure>


    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)

    'get all isolationProcedureEnd
    ie = From el In xe...<isolationProcedureEnd> Select el

    'increment id
    For Each f As XElement In ie
        Dim IDAttr As XAttribute = f.Attribute("id")
        If IDAttr Is Nothing Then
            Stop 'NO id Attribute
        Else
            Stop 'has id Attribute
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realized all I needed to do was add an increment variable then on first iteration change the step id value.